# VBA unable to get anchor element in table?

Tags: html, vba, dom

I'm trying to click an anchor element on a web page.  I'm using this code:

```
 For each anchor in HTMLDoc.anchors
      If anchor.onclick = "validateForm(frmSearchEntry)" Then
           anchor.click
           exit for
      End if
 Next anchor
```

And here is the snippet of html:

```
<tr>
    <td height="35" align="right" nowrap>
    <input type="hidden" name="aisposm01formReset" value="">        
    <a href="#" onclick="return resetForm(frmSearchEntry)"><img src="/Settlement/static/images/pbs/funcreset.gif" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#" onclick="validateForm(frmSearchEntry)"><img src="/Settlement/static/images/pbs/funcsearch.gif" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td valign="bottom" nowrap>
         <table>
            <tr><td name="txtErrorMessage" class="error"></td></tr>
         </table>
       </td>
</tr>
```

However, for some reason when I try to execute the code it just flies right over the for next loop as if there are no anchor elements anywhere on the page.  I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated to reflect the answer the question noted in the comments*

The elements you are trying to find are not actually anchors.  See [this link](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html) for a description of how anchors are implemented in html. An anchor looks like this `<a name="anchor"></a>` and you would create a link to it like so `<a href="#anchor">click here</a>`.

Instead, I you could use `HTMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("A")` to get all of the links and then iterate through those.  Make sure you perform your check based on the `.getAttribute` function as noted below.

---

The `.OnClick` function returns a pointer to the event handling function per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  What you probably want instead is `.getAttribute(strAttributeName As String, Optional lFlags As Long)` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Try (UNTESTED):

```
For each linkelement in HTMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("a")   'As noted above
      If linkelement.getAttribute("OnClick") = "validateForm(frmSearchEntry)" Then
           linkelement.click
           exit for
      End if
Next anchor
```

If that doesn't work right away, put a breakpoint on the If statement and check the value of `anchor.getAttribute("OnClick")` in the Watch Window.

Comment: I may need to post more of the HTML, and I'm sorry that I didn't make it more clear in the first question, but the macro doesn't even enter the loop.  When it hits the For Each line it simply flies right past it as if there were no anchor elements in the HTML document.  So, much as I appreciate your suggestions and they may come in handy getting the click working I still need to get it to actually recognize that tag in the first place.  I may simply have to loop through all cells on the page... yeah... then I could try your suggestion.  Might just get it.  I'll have to report back tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, I see - I read "flies right over the for next loop" to mean "flies right **through**...".  I'll try to take another look as I have the time and update the answer accordingly.